# gen solution of second order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

can anyone please start me off on how to go about solving this differential equation.
I'm unsure of which method to use.

$$ (1-x^2)\frac{\mathrm d^2y}{\mathrm d x^2} + 4x \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx} = 0. $$
thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: Separation of variables should work: Let $z = \frac{\mathrm dy}{\mathrm dx}$, then your equation reads $\def\d{\mathrm d}$ 
$$ (1-x^2)\frac{\d z}{\d x} = -4x\, z \iff \frac{\d z}z = -\frac{4x}{1-x^2} $$
Now integrate.